# DataBinding not updating when passing LiveData<?> instead of ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

I am using `DataBinding`, and in my `ViewModel` I have a `LiveData<MyItem>` object which I want to bind to my layout. The item has one attribute like this:

```
@Bindable
public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(int amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.aMOUNT);
}
```

The thing is that if I indicate in the `Fragment`:

```
mDataBinding.setItem(mViewModel)
```

and in the layout I have:

```
<Button
...
android:enabled="@{viewModel.item.amount == 0}/>
```

it binds it and once an attribute *amountt* from *Item* changes, enables or disables a button. OK.

The problem becomes when, instead of passing the viewModel instance, I directly pass the `Item` instance:

```
mDataBinding.setItem(mViewModel.getItem().getValue())
```

and in layout:

```
<Button
...
android:enabled="@{item.amount == 0}/>
```

**the problem then is that it enables/disables the button the first time correctly but it does not changes its state when item's amount attribute changes.** Do you know why does it happen??

Answer (score 1):

Can you set `binding.lifecycleOwner = this` before the viewModel? Also if you use fragment use `lifeCycleOwner` instead of `this`